# Unity 3D Timer seems to be running too fast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the user presses a button fwdi is set to 1 which starts this if statement. It seems logical to me that if I reduce fwdi by 0.1 every update and move the player 0.1 every update then everything should be done by the 1 second mark however the movement is much quicker than 1 second. I have an animation that also plays which takes 1 second and they don't match up.

EDIT

```
void Update ()
{

    if (fwdi > 0.0f)
    {

        fwdi = fwdi - 1.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        amountToMove.y = 1.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate (amountToMove);
        if (fwdi == 0.0f)
        {

            amountToMove.y = 0.0f;
            fwdi = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you should need to do in compensate for frametime (IE: at 60fps, update is called 60times per second)

```
void Update ()
{
    if (fwdi > 0)
    {
        amountToMove.y = 0.1f*Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate (amountToMove);
        fwdi = fwdi - amountToMove.y;
        //This code bellow looks redundant, and probably unnecessary
        if (fwdi == 0)
        {
            amountToMove.y = 0;
            fwdi = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider putting movement on `FixedUpdate`.  Fixed update works similarly to update with a few key differents:

-Fixedupdate has priority over the normal update function,

-unity default call cap for fixed update is 20 times per second

It's commonly suggested that you put, **lightweight** processes that benefit from predictable update intervals on fixed update, like movement and physics.

**Note**:: its still a good idea to multiply everything in `FixedUpdate`  by `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, just in case Fixedupdate fails to reach its 20 tick per second count.

Comment: Thanks, I've got the time sorted so that actually counts in real time now. I had the script attached to a non active object, once I deleted that the timing was back to normal for some reason. It's almost perfect now however every time I move the player so amountToMove.y = 1.0f, it actually moves it closer to 1.02f which doesn't sound like much however it is noticeable. Is there any way to make this stop dead on 1? I've updated with what I have, thanks for you help. I've tried with FixedUpdate and fixedDeltaTime however this produces a greater difference than without using fixed.

Comment: Removing the second if statement has improved the result slightly however the move distance it is still greater than it should be by a tiny amount.

Comment: `if(amountToMove.y > 1.0f) amountToMove.y = 1.0f;`

Comment: @SpunkTrumpet Post this as a new question, and I can try to give it a proper answer, it's a pretty well known issue that plages things like pathfinding and physics. it's worth understanding why it happens and how to avoid it on a case by case basis

Answer (score 1):

- [Time.timeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)
- [Frame rate](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/80027-Not-frame-rate-independent)
- [Time.deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Now I know almost nothing about Unity, so this may not be close to an answer. Normally you would make things in games frame rate independent by calculating a factor, say if you wan't to move 1 distance in one second, you calculated time passed and apply a multiplication. E.g. "timepassed-factor  * amounttomove"

From what I can gather you need to use `Time.deltaTime` which would give you the actual time passed between frames, where as `timeScale` really just is for slow motion etc...

So... amountToMove.y = 1f * Time.deltaTime * ???;